# Swift 3: FirebaseDB returning nil when child is present

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have linked Firebase to my app. When I'm trying to read data from the DB, data is present in the snapshot. But when a child is read, it returns nil.

Here's the code:

```
    func checkForDuplicateScan(qrCode: String) {

    DataService.ds.REF_SAMPLES.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            print(dict)
            print(qrCode)
            print(dict["\(qrCode)"])
            if let sampleDict = dict[qrCode] as? [String:Any] {
                print(sampleDict)
                if let isScanned = sampleDict["scanned"] as? Bool {
                    if isScanned == true {
                        print("Already Scanned")
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Already Redeemed", message: "This offer has already been redeemed by you. Stay tuned.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (alert) in
                            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                        }))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        print("New Scan")
                        self.updateQRCode(qrCode: qrCode)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Error: can't read/find 'scanned' ")
                }
            }else {
                print("Error: Invalid Code Scanned")
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid QR Code Scanned", message: "The code that you've scanned is Invalid.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (alert) in
                    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: can't get dictionary from snapshot value")
        }
    })
}
```

Here's the console log:

[image: Console log]

The log:

1. The dictionary came from printing dict.
   print(dict)
2. The 'test13' came from
   print(qrCode)
3. The 'nil' came from
   print(dict["\(qrCode)"])

This code was working as of yesterday but has failed today.

Help me out!!

Edit: This is the data that I'm trying to read.

[image]

Here's the JSON file as well [JSON FILE](https://pastebin.com/MkCtpSLN)

Update: Looks like I've found out the problem here.

When I run this code, nothing is printed.

```
if let newDict = dict[qrCode] as? NSDictionary {
     print(newDict)
}
```

But, when I do this, the dict is accessible.

```
if let newDict = dict["test10"] as? NSDictionary {
     print(newDict)
}
```

Note that *qrCode* is a string having value "*test10*"

Wierd asf!! Still can't figure the reason behind it and how to rectify this.

Comment: I have no idea which line(s) in the log come from what code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just something to check, your problem seems to be with data type and not with Firebase data. Hence, you are getting the "Error: Invalid Code Scanned".
I always go with something like:

```
if let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
    let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
    etc ...
}
```

[String:Any] has caused problems for me in the past. Anyhow, it would be helpful to provide a sample of your data which you're trying to read.

Comment: Forgive me but I'm still confused as to where qrCode is coming from. I don't see it in the example JSON you have. I think it is the qrCode which is giving you the headache.

Comment: the 'test9', 'test10', 'test11' etc are the values of qrCode

Answer (score 0):

While the code should print, it looks like a bad approach anyway. You're downloading all QR codes from the database to the client, to then check if one of them exists. The more data is in the database, the more data you'll download for each check. It's much more efficient to attach the observer one level lower in the database:

```
func checkForDuplicateScan(qrCode: String) {
  DataService.ds.REF_SAMPLES.child(qrCode).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        if let sampleDict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
            if let isScanned = sampleDict["scanned"] as? Bool {
                if isScanned == true {
```

Comment: Optional(<null>)

This is what I'm getting

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like we're missing something. Let's try a different approach. I updated my answer to show a more efficient way to doing this.

Comment: Still won't work. Can't think of a reason why it won't work. :|